# How to store a Python dictionary as an Environment Variable

Tags: python, dictionary, environment-variables

I am trying to store an Environment Variable that Python can read in as a Dictionary. If this is a bad idea, please let me know your suggestions, I am eager to learn. I'm worried that if I store the data as many environment variables it might become hard to manage.

I programmed a Raspberry Pi to unlock a door based off the Caller ID's of incoming phone calls to a Twilio number, it is working great. I want to share my code on Github for feedback but I do not want to share my list of phone numbers with the world so I am trying to save it as an environment variable and then let Python read it in.

The phone numbers are in a Python Dictionary like this.

```
building_admins = {
    "+27792955555": "De Wet",
    "+27722855555": "Marysol",
    "+27878085555": "Blomerus",
}
```

I am trying to save it as an Environment Variable like this on Ubuntu 14.04

```
export BUILDING_ADMINS='{
    "+27792955555": "De Wet",
    "+27722855555": "Marysol",
    "+27878085555": "Blomerus",
}'
```

1) I can't get Linux to save the environment variable, is there something I could do to make it work?

2) I feel like there must be a better way to do this and I am going in the wrong direction but nothing I seem to find with Googling is solving the problem I am facing. Please point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An environment variable is not something a script user would like to set. Use the `json` module and a file:

```
import json

with open('numbers') as f:
    numbers = json.load(f)

print numbers['+27792955555']    #  De Wet
```

When pushing to GitHub don't commit the `numbers` file. Maybe commit an example one and add the real one to your `.gitignore`.

Comment: Make sure to not upload `numbers.json` by either ignoring it in the `.gitignore` of your repo or placing it and reading it from a dotfile in the user's home directory, and therefore outside the repo (e.g. `~/.numbers.json`). Also see [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) if you choose the latter option.

Answer (score 19):

I don't know if this is what you were looking for, but I ended up here while trying to save a dictionary as a Linux environment variable to consume it on my app.

What I did was saving it as a string like this:

```
export BUILDING_ADMINS="{'+27792955555': 'De Wet','+27722855555': 'Marysol','+27878085555': 'Blomerus'}'
```

And then on your python code you read it and transform it into a dictionary using this (taken from: [Convert a String representation of a Dictionary to a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988228/convert-a-string-representation-of-a-dictionary-to-a-dictionary)):

```
import ast
import os

ba_dict = ast.literal_eval(os.environ["BUILDING_ADMINS"])
```

If you type

```
type(ba_dict)
```

You should see your string is now a dict.

```
<class 'dict'>
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Answer (score 6):

There is a option named environs, unfortunately, the way of exporting is a little different from the one you want, but I will suggest you because can be an alternative for you or other people (I needed to do this another day).

https://pypi.org/project/environs/

```
pip install environs
```

You can export via terminal or even creating a `.env` file

```
export BUILDING_ADMINS=+27792955555=De Wet,+27722855555=Marysol, +27878085555=Blomerus
```

In the code:

```
from environs import Env

env = Env()
env.read_env() // to allow reading from .env file

building_admins = env.dict('BUILDING_ADMINS', subcast=str)
```

result:

```
print(building_admins)
```

```
{
    "+27792955555": "De Wet",
    "+27722855555": "Marysol",
    "+27878085555": "Blomerus",
}
```

Comment: Hope it works, because this is exactly what I need:-)

Answer (score 5):

If you choose to use the environment, you should serialize the Python dictionary as JSON and dump/load that when setting/getting the environment variable. You can access the environment using `os` module's `environ` attribute. You can dump/load JSON using the `json` module. You might want to watch out for a maximum length on environment variables if there is such a thing.

If I were you I would use a sqlite database, see https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html. This would give you persistence, a defined schema, and a nice interface for handling your data.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `environ` just because of the fact that the library does some extra safety checking and has seen all kinds of use cases.

https://pypi.org/project/environs/

```
pip install environs
```

Your `config.py`

```
import environ

# Django cookiecutter does it like this.
env = environ.Env()
ROOT_DIR = (
    environ.Path(__file__)
) # let's say your configs sit at the root of the project and it's called .env
env.read_env(str(ROOT_DIR.path(".env")))

# Your env variable looks like a JSON
# There are multiple types available that you can go for if you don't think JSON is correct.
BUILDING_ADMINS = env.json('BUILDING_ADMINS')
```

```py
>> from configs import *
>> print(BUILDING_ADMINS)
{
    "+27792955555": "De Wet",
    "+27722855555": "Marysol",
    "+27878085555": "Blomerus"
}
>> type(BUILDING_ADMINS)
<class 'dict'>
```

Answer (score 1):

Old thread, but here's how I do it for **large** dictionaries:

1- Make a compressed `json` object:

```
{"FOO":"BAR","NAME":"JOHN"}
```

2- base64 encode the string-dict, so it becomes something like this:

```
eyJGT08iOiJCQVIiLCJOQU1FIjoiSk9ITiJ9
```

3- Now you can `export` it as an env var.

4- base64 decode it in your code and do a `json.loads(decoded_string)` to get your dictionary :)

Answer (score 0):

As I didn't want to have to insert a new package environs, I tried all others exposed solutions, but in Python 3.6, none worked for me.

My solution for tranform this below env variable into dict object is :

```
MY_ENV_VAR_DICT="{'test1':'test1','test2':'test2'}"
```

Code:

```
import os

my_dict = eval(os.environ['MY_ENV_VAR_DICT'].replace('"',''))
print(my_dict.items())
```

Output :

```
dict_items([('test1', 'test1'), ('test2', 'test2')])
```

This works fine for me (with no superfluous imports) ! :)

Answer (score -2):

It is possible! Just do

```
import os
os.environ.__dict__["_data"]["yourkey"] = {"key":0} #Your data
print (os.environ.__dict__["_data"]["yourkey"]) #Will print out value!
```

It's a little complicated but works!

Comment: While setting `os.environ['TEST'] = 'test'` does mean that running `!echo $TEST` in an ipython shell will output the correct value, when you start trying to stuff dictionaries in it will explode.